# Relational style list lookups

Tags: list

I would like to build a Sharepoint 2010  list that pulls in data looked  up  automatically from another list on the same site.

In SQL this would be "select List1.*,List2.* from List1, List2where List1.userid=List2.userid"

Currently List1 looks like

action,   userid,

read     user1
edit     user1
read     user 2

etc..

List2 comprises

userid,  Userfirstname, UserSurname

user1    Fred           Smith
user2    Joe            Bloggs

I want to build View ActionReports as follows

action,   userid,   LookedUpFirstname, LookedUpSurname.
read      user1     Fred               Smith
edit      user1     Fred               Smith
read      user2     Joe                Bloggs

etc....

Or even concatenate the last two together....

Oh & then use it with ClientContext for an external app too

Many thanks

Richard

Answer (score 1):

Just use lookup columns for your first question: [Lookup Columns](http://weblogs.asp.net/bsimser/archive/2009/10/19/sp2010-what-s-new-lookup-columns-spc09.aspx) and to join them either use [SP.Services](http://spservices.codeplex.com/), [REST API](http://dotnet-forum.de/blogs/thorstenhans/archive/2010/07/14/sharepoint-2010-restful-api.aspx) or the [Client Object Model](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/60348/SharePoint-2010-Client-Object-Model-for-JavaScript).

I would like to give a more precise answer if you give us some more information or some sample code.